# Creating vertical lines in an html page containing image and text

Tags: html, css

I want to have two vertical lines at each side of the page (left and right), and I saw several ways to do it, some of them were suggested here in Stack Overflow, but none of them solved this little issue I have.
What I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

How I tried to achieve it:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Enter Title Here</title>
        <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background-color: #BCD2EE;
            margin-left: 20%;
            margin-right: 20%;
            padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
        }
        .verticalLine {
            border-left: thick solid #4876FF;
            border-right: thick solid #4876FF;
        }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="verticalLine">
        <h3 style="color:#1912D8">Welcome!</h3>

        <div><p style="float: left; padding: 5px 30px 10px 50px;"><img src="default.jpg" height=350 width=350></p></div>

        <div><p style="font-size:20px;">
        <br>Text
        <br>Text
        <br>Text

        </p></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

What I actually get:

[image]

Notice that the vertical lines do not go all the way down, and only encompass the text, but not the image nor the whole page.
How can I fix it to get what I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this with just add `overflow:hidden;` property on your `.verticalLine` div

```
.verticalLine {
    border-left: thick solid #4876FF;
    border-right: thick solid #4876FF;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Or if you want to do it in the `body` tag you may want to visit this link: http://css-tricks.com/pseudo-element-roundup/ there's an article about `creating body border` there :)